# AngularJS ngResource without call back exception Error: noop is not a function

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ngresource

```
$scope.validate = function () {
        $scope.model.$validate({ value: $scope.model }, {}, function(response) {
            $scope.modelState = response.data.ModelState;
        });
    }

return $resource(baseUrl, null, { 'validate': { method: 'PUT', params: { id: 0 } } }).get({ id: Id });
```

Calling a resource which consumes a web api controller I receive the following exception:

Error: noop is not a function resourceFactory/http://localhost:55470/Scripts/angular-resource.js:626:18 processQueue@http://localhost:55470/Scripts/angular.js:13189:27 scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost:55470/Scripts/angular.js:13205:27 $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://localhost:55470/Scripts/angular.js:14401:16 $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://localhost:55470/Scripts/angular.js:14217:15 $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttp://localhost:55470/Scripts/angular.js:14506:13 done@http://localhost:55470/Scripts/angular.js:9659:36 completeRequest@http://localhost:55470/Scripts/angular.js:9849:7 requestLoaded@http://localhost:55470/Scripts/angular.js:9790:1

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.validate = function () {
        $scope.model.$validate({ value: $scope.model }, $.noop, function (response) {
            $scope.modelState = response.data.ModelState;
        });
    }
```

Looks as if you cannot pass a new object to the success handler..